# Bootstrap PopoverX Methods Not Firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, popover

I have been trying to get the bootstrap extension popover X to work (http://plugins.krajee.com/popover-x)

I setup a JS fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wp80d5ux/2/), but the popover does not seem to load.

Below is my example.

Am I loading the libraries improperly?

```
<BR><BR><BR><BR><button id="#btn1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Top</button>
<script>
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    // initialize popover on click of `#btn1`
    $('#btn1').popoverButton({
        target: '#myPopover1'
    });
    // or alternatively initialize popover on hover of `#btn1`
    $('#btn1').popoverButton({
        target: '#myPopover1',
        trigger: 'hover focus'
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the javascript console? Have you loaded bootstrap/the popper script?

Comment: Yes.  1.  "Uncaught Error: Bootstrap dropdown require Popper.js"...which I've included as a library.  2. Uncaught TypeError: bootstrap-popover-x.min.js line 10 Cannot read property 'Constructor' of undefined  -- not clear why

Comment: Can you add this to your jsfiddle?

Comment: The errors are both in the JSFiddle...which you look at developer tools, you should see the errors.

Comment: I reorded the popper script in the fiddle. It needs to load before bootstrap, which needs to load before popover-x, so now no more console errors

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me locally, but i cannot get it to work on jsfiddle for some reason... (works on [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FPyyjjmE7TgqgGPWm5Pz?p=preview))

```
<BR><BR><BR><BR><button type="button" id='btn1' class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Top</button>


<div id="myPopover1" style='display:none' class="popover popover-x popover-default">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <div class="popover-header popover-title"><button class="close" data-dismiss="popover-x">&times;</button>Title</div>
    <div class="popover-body popover-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="popover-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button><button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary">Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(()=>{
    $('#btn1').popoverButton({
        target: '#myPopover1'
    });       
})
</script>
```

Bootstrap 4 code here

```
 <div id="myPopover2" style="display: none" class="popover popover-default">
        <div class="arrow"></div>
        <div class="popover-title"><span class="close pull-right" data-dismiss="popover-x">&times;</span>Title</div>
        <div class="popover-content">
             <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aeneancommodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
        </div>
 </div>
 <button type="button"  id='weinz' class="btn btn-secondary">
      Popover on top
 </button>
<script>
    $(document).ready(()=>{
       $('#weinz').popover({
        content:$('#myPopover2')
       }) 
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks, though it does not seem to be working as the plugin intends.  It seems to be acting as a full modal...because the background changes

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using the plugin, rather than the builtin Bootstrap 4. I added a second button that uses just built in bootstrap rather than an external plugin.